# How to insert a list into the specific elements?

Tags: python

I have two list :

```
T1=[[['A'], ['C']], [['B'], ['C']]]
T2=[[['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]]
```

I want to combine the two:

I tried this:

```
for i in range(len(T2)):
      T1.insert(i,T2)
```

the result show like this:

```
[[[['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]], [[['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]], [['A'], ['C']], [['B'], ['C']]]
```

But i want result should be :

```
[[[['A'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]], [[['B'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]]]
```

Comment: can you explain more? because between all the `[[` and just 3 items it's difficult to know what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T1=[[['A'], ['C']], [['B'], ['C']]]
T2=[[['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]]

final = []
for i in T1:
    ans= []
    ans.append(i)
    for j in T2:
        ans.append(j)

    final.append(ans)
print final
```

The output will be:

```
[[[['A'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]], [[['B'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B']], [['B'], ['A']]]]
```

Want the user wants is something like this:

```
 [
        [
            [[’A’], [’C’]], [[’A’], [’B’]], [[’B’], [’A’]]
        ], 
        [
            [[’B’], [’C’]], [[’A’], [’B’]], [[’B’], [’A’]]
        ]
]
```

The first element from the first list `T1` to be combined with the elements of the other list `T2`.

Comment: the answer is as unclear as the question...

Comment: what didn't you understand @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: well, everything.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have edited my answer to make it more readable what keavy wants. I hope it's clear now.